# What is the use of "?" in jquery

Tags: javascript

What is the use of "?" mark ?
can anyone explain what question mark is doing here.

```
0 ? 1 : 1+w
```

and also ":" symbol .
How to use "?" while writing the codes..

I have seen so many codes where people will use "?" like example above.

can anyone explain what question mark is doing.

Comment: That is not jQuery. That is a short if else statement. Can't think of the name.. anyone?

Comment: it is the ternary operator from javascript

Comment: in the given case always `1+w` will get executed as 0 is always falsy

Comment: i have seen this in jsfiddle. they have used like newTop = (scroll > 0 ? t : t - mh);

Comment: Like Arun suggested it, i don't think you have seen that anywhere, doesn't make sense: `0 ? 1 : 1+w`

Comment: So `newTop = (scroll > 0 ? t : t - mh)` means: `if(scroll > 0){newTop = t}else{newTop = t - mh}`

Comment: It's always advisable to learn the programming language first, before learning frameworks. Just saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's called ternary operator, a kind of conditional operator

```
var fooNotNull = (foo !== null) ? true : false;
```

if the first condition is 'true', it is saved in the variable 'fooNotNull', else the second value 'false' is stored in 'footNotNull'

Comment: Of course in this example the ternary operator is overkill, you could just write `var fooNotNull = (foo !== null)`

Answer (score 3):

This is nothing to do with jquery, this is standard javascript.  It's known as a ternary operator.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

This:

```
x = a ? b : c
```

is the equivalent of writing:

```
if (a) {
  x = b 
} else {
  x = c
}
```

Comment: The fact that it's ternary is just an aspect, a property of the Conditional Operator. It just means that it takes 3 operands. Incidentally, it is the only ternary operator in JavaScript and many C-like languages.

Answer (score 1):

It has  nothing to do with jquery. it is javascript `if else` shorthand method

Check below example

```
var big;
if (x > 10) {
    big = true;
}
else {
    big = false;
}
```

**shorthand**

```
var big = (x > 10) ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression is a tenerary operator. It works like an 'if' and 'else'.
Whatever is before the '?' is evaluated, returning what is after the '?' when the condition is true, and whatever is after the ':' if it is false.

These expressions give the same results:

```
a = 0 ? 1 : 1+w

if(0){
    a = 1;
}else{
    a = 1 + w;
}
```